# How to change Opacity of an object

Tags: java, android, opacity

I am trying to make an Object transparent (say, ImageView) I know about Alpha but it only changes the intensity of color, I am talking about "see through" transparency so you can see an ImageView beneath the other.

Comment: Alpha changes transparency as indeed.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos please explain with code :/

Comment: Call setAlpha(0.5f) on your view and you will see, the Shef answer was edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
view.setAlpha();//anything b/w 0f to 1f
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [View.setAlpha(float alpha)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29).

Alpha values varies from 0.0f to 1.0f.